# First Parameterized Subset of Primes that was Related to a Mathematical Result

Tags: ho.history-overview, prime-numbers

To my knowledge, Fermat primes, i.e. primes of the form $2^{2^n}+1$ were the first to play a role in a mathematical result, namely in the characterization of constructible regular n-gons. Gauss discovered the constructability of the regular Heptadecagon (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagonhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon) in 1796.
Not much later, in 1805, Sophie Germain proved Fermat's conjecture for primes $p$ for which $2p+1$ is also prime.

**My Question is:**
Have there been any mathematical results, that are not related to the properties of prime numbers and, were found prior to Gauss' discovery of the constructability of the regular Heptadecagon, that were formulated via a proper subset of the prime numbers, that was characterized via a parameterized expression.

Comment: Do primes of the form 4k+1 count? (Fermat and Euler on sums of two squares.)  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2014.03.31

Comment: We have those of the form $2n+1$, too :-)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I would not count primes of the form 4k+1 as an example, because they are related to a theorem about properties of prime numbers, but I admit that I need to edit my question in that respect.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez What is the related mathematical result that was found prior to Gauss?

Comment: @ManfredWeis, Euclid had shown the infinity of primes of that form, say!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't want theorems or results that are concerned with properties of primes, but rather problems, in which certain categories of primes provide a solution or at least a progress (see John Stillwells example or, my examples).

Comment: The theorem is about certain numbers which are the sum of two squares, and happens to use prime decomposition to describe them.  However, you know what you are looking for.  I don't know that.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2014.04.01

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman: I was not familiar with the the result you are relating to, so I feed it into my search engine; the outcome was a condition for primes being expressible as the sum of two squares. From my original formulation of the question that was acceptable, but I admitted my fault and reformulated accordingly.

Comment: I really don't understand, why the topic is considered to be too broad; I guess that prior to Gauss, there weren't that many results with specific prime numbers as an outcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An earlier example than the Fermat primes is the class of primes
of the form $2^n-1$, the so-called Mersenne primes. These occur in
Euclid's theorem that $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ is perfect when $2^n-1$ is
prime, and in the complementary theorem of Euler that these are all
the even perfect numbers.

Comment: very nice example; I would be surprised if something earlier would be found